# Working with tables: add new level of nested tables

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation, tuples

I am trying to obtain all possible combinations of elements in a (long) list

```
factors = {A, B, C}; 
getCombinations[factors,n]
```

For n = 3 factors, it should give

```
getCombinations[factors,3] 
{{{A^3, A^2 B, A^2 C}, {A B^2, A B C}, {A C^2}}, {{B^3, 
   B^2 C}, {B C^2}}, {{C^3}}}
```

I'm stuck trying to extend it for "n" number of factors.

For n=3 I have

```
len = Length[fac];
Table[fac[[i]]*
  Table[fac[[j]]*
    Table[fac[[k]],
     {k, j, len}],
   {j, i, len}],
 {i, 1, len}]
```

**SOLUTION (EDIT)**

Both users cvgmt and Syed posted working solutions. Thank you so much!
Based on the solution of cvgmt:

```
getCombinations[factors_, m_Integer] := 
 Module[{list,  n = Length[factors]},
  list = FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, n], m];
  Inner[Power, factors, #, Times] & /@ list // Sort]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `FrobeniusSolve` to solve the equation
$$x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n= m $$
Here `n` and `m` may not the same.

```
Clear[m, n, list];
n = 4;
m = 4;
list = FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, n], m];
Inner[Power, Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, n], #, Times] & /@ list // Sort
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One possible implementation could be:

```
getCombinations[n_Integer] := Module[{t},
  t = Select[Tuples[Range[n, 0, -1], {n}], Total@# == n &];
  Map[Times @@ Power[ToExpression /@Alphabet[][[1 ;; n]], #] &, t, {1}]
  ]

getCombinations[3]
```

$$\left\{a^3,a^2 b,a^2 c,a b^2,a b c,a c^2,b^3,b^2 c,b c^2,c^3\right\}$$

```
getCombinations[4]
```

$$\left\{a^4,a^3 b,a^3 c,a^3 d,a^2 b^2,a^2 b c,a^2 b d,a^2 c^2,a^2 c d,a^2 d^2,a b^3,a b^2 c,a b^2 d,a b c^2,a b c d,a b d^2,a c^3,a c^2 d,a c d^2,a d^3,b^4,b^3 c,b^3 d,b^2 c^2,b^2 c d,b^2 d^2,b c^3,b c^2 d,b c d^2,b d^3,c^4,c^3 d,c^2 d^2,c d^3,d^4\right\}$$

---

**EDIT**

To make it more general:

```
getCombinationsFromFactors[n_Integer, k_List] := Module[{t},
  t = Select[Tuples[Range[n, 0, -1], {Length@k}], Total@# == n &];
  Map[Times @@ Power[k, #] &, t, {1}]
  ]

getCombinationsFromFactors[3, {a, b, f}]
```

$$\left\{a^3,a^2 b,a^2 f,a b^2,a b f,a f^2,b^3,b^2 f,b f^2,f^3\right\}$$

```
getCombinationsFromFactors[5, {a, b, f}]
```

$${a^5, a^4 b, a^4 f, a^3 b^2, a^3 b f, a^3 f^2, a^2 b^3, a^2 b^2 f, 
 a^2 b f^2, a^2 f^3, a b^4, a b^3 f, a b^2 f^2, a b f^3, a f^4, b^5, 
 b^4 f, b^3 f^2, b^2 f^3, b f^4, f^5}$$

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
factors = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
DeleteDuplicates[Times @@@ Tuples[factors, Length[factors]]];
```

> $
> \left\{\text{a}^4,\text{a}^3 \text{b},\text{a}^3 \text{c},\text{a}^3 \text{d},\text{a}^2 \text{b}^2,\text{a}^2 \text{b} \text{c},\text{a}^2 \text{b} \text{d},\text{a}^2 \text{c}^2,\text{a}^2 \text{c} \text{d},\text{a}^2 \text{d}^2,\text{a} \text{b}^3,\text{a} \text{b}^2 \text{c},\text{a} \text{b}^2 \text{d},\text{a} \text{b} \text{c}^2,\text{a} \text{b} \text{c} \text{d},\text{a} \text{b} \text{d}^2,\text{a} \text{c}^3,\text{a} \text{c}^2 \text{d},\text{a} \text{c} \text{d}^2,\text{a} \text{d}^3,\text{b}^4,\text{b}^3 \text{c},\text{b}^3 \text{d},\text{b}^2 \text{c}^2,\text{b}^2 \text{c} \text{d},\text{b}^2 \text{d}^2,\text{b} \text{c}^3,\text{b} \text{c}^2 \text{d},\text{b} \text{c} \text{d}^2,\text{b} \text{d}^3,\text{c}^4,\text{c}^3 \text{d},\text{c}^2 \text{d}^2,\text{c} \text{d}^3,\text{d}^4\right\}
> $

Comment: This is a brilliant solution as well. But when the number of terms grows so much it becomes computationally more expensive to build the combinations and check for duplicates as opposed to building the terms directly without duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a DFS

```
ClearAll[dfs];
max = 3;
len = 3;
dfs[curVal_, curPos_, curSum_, cur_] := Which[
        curSum > max || curPos > len,      Return[],
        curSum === max && curPos === len,  Sow[cur],
        True,
        Table[
              dfs[val, curPos + 1, curSum + val, Append[cur, val]],
              {val, 0, max - curSum}
              ]
]
Reap[dfs[0, 0, 0, {}]]//
Last//
Last//
Map[
    Inner[Power, Array[a, len], #, Times]&
]
```

> `{a[3]^3, a[2]*a[3]^2, a[2]^2*a[3], a[2]^3, a[1]*a[3]^2, a[1]*a[2]*a[3], a[1]*a[2]^2, a[1]^2*a[3], a[1]^2*a[2], a[1]^3}`